# Как открыть консоль в yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Как открыть консоль в yii2?
Хочу выпонить команду

```
php yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations/
```

для создания в БД таблиц RBAC.

Пытаюсь вызвать в корневой директории приложения yii.bat, но консоль моментально закрывается (что-то не то я делаю).

Comment: Переменная PHP не обьявлена в Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в yii нет консоли командной строкой надо пользоваться win+r там cmd потом cd диск://путь/к yii/ ентер а после этого вашу команду и будет вам счастье